# Only white rectangle appears after adding a subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib, addsubview, loadnibnamed

I'm trying to add a subview with this code:

```
NSArray *subviewArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"subView" owner:self options:nil];
SubView *subView = [subviewArray objectAtIndex:0];
[self.view addSubview:subView];
```

But only a white rectangle appears, however with the correct size.
The `SubView`'s initialization methods aren't called at all. (The `initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder` should be called in this case, but isn't.)

The xib's owner is the SubView class. This is a view and not a controller.

What could cause this malfunction, and what would be the proper solution?

Comment: try to setFrame of menuView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code to create `view` from `xib`:

```
UINib *menuNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"MenuView" bundle:nil];
NSArray *aNib = [menuNib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
UIView *menuView = [aNib objectAtIndex:0];
```